# trouble with for loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

As i really like Programming and i like to program in my free time so i was trying to create a code in which the output would look like an x. Something like this.

```
x    x
 x  x
  x
 x  x
x    x
```

So i wanted the user to input the height of the "x". This is the code i have so far and i really don't know how to move on. I just need a hint or if anyone can tell me where i went wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;    
    public class x{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    int height;    
    System.out.print("Enter the height of the X:   " );             
    height = kbd.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++){                        
      for (int j = 1; j <= height; j++) {                            
        if(i ==j || j+i == height + 1)                               
            System.out.println("x");                            
        else                            
            System.out.print(" ");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you want to print only 1 line of "x"-es? or some table?

Comment: Java is indexed at 0, not 1.

Comment: You don't always need new line after `x` in `System.out.println("x"); ` correct this.

Comment: oh actually i think Grijesh deserves to be the answerer of this question.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus That is correct if you are iterating an array or a list. However, here it is just a counter in a for-loop, and the break condition is using `<=`, so for this particular use case it does not matter.

Answer (score 5):

Two changes:

- change `System.out.println("x");` to `System.out.print("x");`  (remove ln after print)
- after the two lines

  ```
      System.out.print(" ");
  }
  ```

  add

  ```
  System.out.println();
  ```

Comment: "add System.out.println(); after the line System.out.print(" ");" surely not straight after, but after the }, or else each blank space will get a new line

Comment: that's right, Richard. thanks for the heads up! i'll edit answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){                        
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {                            
        if(i == j || j + i == height - 1)                               
            System.out.print("x");                            
        else                            
            System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me for both odd and even height's of X:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
public class x{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    int height;    
    System.out.print("Enter the height of the X:   " );             
    height = kbd.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++){                        
      for (int j = 0; j <= height; j++) {                            
        if( (i ==j && i!=0 ) || j+i == height + 1) //needed to check for i or j !=0
            System.out.print("x"); //this shouldn't be println             
        else                            
            System.out.print(" ");
      }
      System.out.println(); //you needed this
    }
  }
}
```